# Axis step child::element('':PRODUCT_LIST) cannot be used here: the context item is an atomic value

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Thanks in advance for your support.

I have the following xml and xslt

```
<SUBSCRIBER>
    <PRODUCT_LIST>
        <PRODUCT_INFO>
            <ID>BA3</ID>
            <PRODUCT_TYPE>Chargeable Bonus Product</PRODUCT_TYPE>
            <NSN1>34178</NSN1>
            <NSN2>2015-02-18 23:59:59</NSN2>
            <OFFER>1104</OFFER>
            <DA_UNIT>time</DA_UNIT>
            <UA>1003</UA>
        </PRODUCT_INFO>
        <PRODUCT_INFO>
            <ID>SID15</ID>
            <PRODUCT_TYPE>Rate Cutter</PRODUCT_TYPE>
            <NSN1>2015-12-23</NSN1>
            <OFFER>1215</OFFER>
        </PRODUCT_INFO>
        <PRODUCT_INFO>
            <ID>UseRs325GetRs25</ID>
            <PRODUCT_TYPE>Usage Subscription- Traffic</PRODUCT_TYPE>
            <NSN1>0</NSN1>
            <NSN2>2015-02-15</NSN2>
            <NSN3>2015-02-05</NSN3>
            <NSN4>2015-02-15 14:01:33</NSN4>
            <OFFER>1250</OFFER>
            <UA>1095</UA>
            <UA2>1096</UA2>
            <THRESHOLD>325</THRESHOLD>
            <UA_INTERVAL>10</UA_INTERVAL>
        </PRODUCT_INFO>
    </PRODUCT_LIST>
</SUBSCRIBER>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="SUBSCRIBER">

    <xsl:variable name="PRODUCT_TYPE" select="PRODUCT_LIST/PRODUCT_INFO[(PRODUCT_TYPE eq 'Chargeable Bonus Product') or (PRODUCT_TYPE eq 'Home Zone') or (PRODUCT_TYPE eq 'Usage Subscription- Traffic') or (PRODUCT_TYPE eq 'Telescopic Charging') or (PRODUCT_TYPE eq 'Usage Subscription- Recharge')]/PRODUCT_TYPE"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="1 to count($PRODUCT_TYPE)">
        <xsl:variable name="index" select="."/>
        <xsl:variable name="product_name" select="$PRODUCT_TYPE[$index]"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="PRODUCT_LIST/PRODUCT_INFO[(PRODUCT_TYPE eq $product_name)]/UA"/>
    </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
```

I am getting the following exception,

Description: Axis step child::element('':PRODUCT_LIST) cannot be used here: the context item is an atomic value

Please advise the fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message says it all - when you are inside a for-each over `1 to count($PRODUCT_TYPE)` the context item (`.`) is a number rather than a node, so you can't use a relative XPath in the `value-of`. You need to save the context item from outside the for-each in another variable and then use paths relative to that:

```
<xsl:variable name="dot" select="."/><!-- . here is the SUBSCRIBER -->
<xsl:for-each select="1 to count($PRODUCT_TYPE)">
    <xsl:variable name="index" select="."/><!-- . here is the number -->
    <xsl:variable name="product_name" select="$PRODUCT_TYPE[$index]"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$dot/PRODUCT_LIST/PRODUCT_INFO[(PRODUCT_TYPE eq $product_name)]/UA"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Though as the other answers point out, you would do better in the long term to restructure your code to use a more standard XSLT processing style rather than simply trying to transplant structures like `for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)` that you are familiar with from more imperative programming languages.  Yes, it takes a while to get used to the more functional way of thinking but it will lead to simpler and more maintainable code in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply change:

```
<xsl:for-each select="1 to count($PRODUCT_TYPE)">
```

to

```
<xsl:for-each select="$PRODUCT_TYPE">
```

Then you will be in the context of `<PRODUCT_TYPE>` and you only need:

```
<xsl:value-of select="../UA"/>
```

to get the sibling `<UA>` value directly, without all that elaborate stretching around that you do.

---

Even simpler would be to define the first variable as:

```
<xsl:variable name="PRODUCT_INFO" select="PRODUCT_LIST/PRODUCT_INFO[(PRODUCT_TYPE eq 'Chargeable Bonus Product') or (PRODUCT_TYPE eq 'Home Zone') or (PRODUCT_TYPE eq 'Usage Subscription- Traffic') or (PRODUCT_TYPE eq 'Telescopic Charging') or (PRODUCT_TYPE eq 'Usage Subscription- Recharge')]"/>
```

and then within:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$PRODUCT_INFO">
```

reach for:

```
<xsl:value-of select="UA"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need any of the variables here

```
<xsl:template match="SUBSCRIBER">
    <!-- filter on PRODUCT_LIST/PRODUCT_INFO/PRODUCT_TYPE -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="PRODUCT_LIST/PRODUCT_INFO[(PRODUCT_TYPE eq 'Chargeable Bonus Product') or (PRODUCT_TYPE eq 'Home Zone') or (PRODUCT_TYPE eq 'Usage Subscription- Traffic') or (PRODUCT_TYPE eq 'Telescopic Charging') or (PRODUCT_TYPE eq 'Usage Subscription- Recharge')]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="PRODUCT_INFO">
    <!-- Get relevant PRODUCT_INFO values -->
    <xsl:value-of select="UA"/>
</xsl:template>
```